# Target text color on hover

Tags: css

I made a css button, but I can't figure out how to change the text color to white when I hover over the button.

```css
    .button1o {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }

    a.button1o:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
    }

    .button1o-text {
    font-size: .7em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #f44336;
    }
```

```html
<a class="button1o" href="" target="_blank">
    <span class="button1o-text">Flat button</span>
    </a>
```

When I add color to

```
a.button1o:hover
```

it doesn't work.

I also tried:

- a.button1o-text:hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are applying the color on the `a` not the `span` try this

```css
.button1o {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #f44336;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #f44336;
}
a.button1o:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
  color: #fff;
}
.button1o-text {
  font-size: .7em;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="button1o" href="" target="_blank">
  <span class="button1o-text">Flat button</span>
</a>
```

In the above snippet i added `color:#fff` to `a.button1o:hover` and also i added `#f44336` to `.button1o`

Another method is like this

```css
.button1o {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #f44336;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
a.button1o:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
  color: #fff;
}
a.button1o:hover span {
  transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
  color: #fff;
}
.button1o-text {
  font-size: .7em;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #f44336;
}
```

```html
<a class="button1o" href="" target="_blank">
  <span class="button1o-text">Flat button</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You put on hover wrongly. You are putting hover on .button1o class but .button1o-text this class is overriding .button1o this color

Please put your code this way

```
.button1o {
background-color: transparent;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
border: 2px solid #f44336;
border-radius: 2px;
}
.button1o-text {
font-size: .7em;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0;
color: #f44336;
}
a.button1o:hover {
background-color: #f44336;
}
span.button1o-text:hover {
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The cleaner option is to move the `color: #f44336` rule out of `.button1o-text` and onto `.button1o`, which will allow the current hover rule to override the color. (Is there a reason you have a span with separate CSS rules at all?)

The other option is to add this hover rule to color the text:

```
.button1o:hover .button1o-text {
  color: [hover color];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the hover property to span element. that is :

```
a.button1o>span:hover {
    color:white;
}
```

Here is a your working code from the question

```css
.button1o {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }

    a.button1o:hover {
      color:white;
    background-color: #f44336;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
    }
a.button1o>span:hover {
      color:white;
  }
    .button1o-text {
    font-size: .7em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #f44336;
    }
```

```html
<a class="button1o" href="" target="_blank">
    <span class="button1o-text">Flat button</span>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqv1zrx9/).

> CODE

This should work as you wanted, tell me if it does, thank you.

```
a.button1o:hover{
background-color: #f44336;
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
}

a.button1o:hover .button1o-text{
color: #fff;
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the span class="button1o-text...
Simply integrate settings into the button1o class and add color:white to the a.button1o:hover class.

```
<a class="button1o" href="" target="_blank">Flat button</a>
```

You might need adding the text-decoration:none attribute into the button1o defintions too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `:hover` selector on the parent element:

```
a.button1o:hover .button1o-text {
    color: white;
}
```

Also you should put the `transition` property inside your first declaration, otherwise you will lose the transition when the user stops hovering over the button.

```
.button1o {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
}

a.button1o:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
}
a.button1o:hover .button1o-text {
    color: white;
}

.button1o-text {
    font-size: .7em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #f44336;
}
```